# Connecting django server to my android app

Tags: android, django, sql-server-2008

I tried the following code but keep getting :

```
ndroidlib.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:8080 refused

 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        String postURL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/users/";
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(postURL);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

and I have in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that server is running and acessible from device? From device's browser, for example.

Comment: yeah the server is running but not acessible from device. by the way, I have router and I'm getting it's IP from ipconfig command in the terminal

Comment: Hi @Dalvik have you figured this out? I realize this is 1 year ago so probably yes. I am trying to choose between Java server and Django, I would like to know if it was easy to connect django to android app?